# GitLab Flutter CI fails with "tojunit: command not found"

Tags: flutter, dart, continuous-integration, gitlab, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to run tests using `junit` and export the report as an XML artifact:

```
image: cirrusci/flutter:stable

before_script:
  - flutter pub get
  - flutter clean
  - flutter --version

stages:
  - analyze-and-test

analyze-and-test:
  stage: analyze-and-test
  script:
    - flutter build aot
    - flutter analyze
   # - flutter test
    - flutter test --machine | tojunit -o report.xml
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - report.xml
  only:
    - master
    - merge_requests
```

The application has the following package dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  junitreport: ^1.3.1
```

When this pipeline is ran, I get the following error:

```
$ flutter test --machine | tojunit -o report.xml
/usr/bin/bash: line 139: tojunit: command not found
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: writeFrom failed, path = '' (OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32)
```

I'm trying to figure out why this is failing. The command should be found since the package is retrieved in `before_script` stanza before the `analyze-and-test` is called. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like tojunit is not installed on CI machine. According to [junitreport installation instruction](https://pub.dev/packages/junitreport#installation) you should run this command to download the program and make a launch script available:

```
pub global activate junitreport
```

So firstly add this command to `before_script` phase:

```
before_script:
 - flutter pub get
 - flutter clean
 - flutter --version
 - flutter pub global activate junitreport
```

Try to run this.

Next, if the `{dart-cache}/bin` directory is not on your path, you will get a warning, including tips on how to fix it. In that case you will need to add some more commands (from tips) to `before_script`.

Comment: `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"` need this command as well